# Concurrent system calls in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, concurrency, system-calls

Simple as this question is, I haven't found anything about it by Googling. Is it safe to make concurrent calls to the Linux system, such as calling `socket()`  on several threads at (what might be) the same time? Specifically, does the kernel guarantee thread-safety for `socket()`, `connect()`, and/or `send()`?

If not, why not? I'd really like to learn more about this topic and why system calls are or are not thread-safe.

My main concern here is really that `socket()` will not return a duplicate or invalid file descriptor when called from different threads. I'm not going to be connecting or writing to the same socket at the same time in my case.

Comment: What does thread-safety mean in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it safe to make concurrent calls to the Linux system, such as
>   calling socket() on several threads at (what might be) the same time?

Yes, they are thread safe. Though I am not sure its just as per the POSIX standard or not.

> Specifically, does the kernel guarantee thread-safety for socket(),
>   connect(), and/or send()?

As per [THIS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.linux.networking/cLbMGRNw8EA) link, yes. It says that locks are used internally, which would mean that your `send` operation would be serialized, but not in any specific order.

Answer to updated part of the question:

> My main concern here is really that socket() will not return a
>   duplicate or invalid file descriptor when called from different
>   threads.

No worries here. OS will make sure that the file descriptors for the socket are not duplicated.

Comment: "Will you *crash the system?"* No.  "Might your threads 'race' and otherwise 'compete' with one another, such that you get thoroughly unpredictable results? Definitely yes.

Comment: Yeah, valid points. But the race condition would be observable only in STREAM protocols, UDP being one shot won't suffer from racing the send buffer data.

Comment: @MikeRobinson in this case I am using TCP sockets, and am never writing to the same socket at the same time. Really, my concern is calling `socket()` and getting a duplicate or invalid file descriptor. As long as that is guaranteed not to happen, I'm happy.

Comment: @RogueCSDev Fear no more. Call to `socket` will not give you already existing file descriptor.

Comment: ... but every *thread* in your *process* shares the same file descriptor. And, basically, even though we think of "sockets," it all comes down to TCP/IP *packets* that are being sent and received one-at-a-time by the hardware.

Comment: @RogueCSDev But beware of closing socket descriptors! You may encounter `ABA` kind of situation if not properly taken care of.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to make sure that each TCP socket "owned by" and accessed only by a particular thread.  That way there is no need to worry about indeterminacy in the ordering of data that gets sent, or in which thread receives which data, or in which thread closes the socket.  With that rule observed, using (different) sockets in different threads simultaneously works fine.

Comment: @MikeRobinson The question wasn't whether threads share file descriptors, though - it was whether calling `socket` twice at the same time might accidentally give you the same file descriptor twice (referring to the same socket).

Answer (score 0):

"Will you *crash the system?"*   No.

"Might your threads 'race' and otherwise 'compete' with one another, such that you get thoroughly unpredictable and un-reproducible results?   Definitely yes.

The kernel generally views resources (such as sockets ...) as being owned by the *process* to which all the threads belong.   <strike>And, if a particular call is "blocking," it's probably going to block the *process.*</strike>

Finally, *socket* actions, such as `send`, really don't *benefit* from the use of threads anyway, because packets are being sent and received through a (comparatively slow ...) *single wire,* one at a time, at millisecond speeds. A simple `select()` polling-loop generally works just fine. "Complexity won't be re-paid."

Comment: Thanks. I'll consider redesigning my application with that in mind.

Comment: Just grab server-code "off the shelf" from GitHub, or from the contributed-library of your programming language of choice. Use it, or directly copy it.

Comment: This answer is misleading -- in particular, a blocking system call will not block the entire process (at least, not on any modern OS).  It will block only the thread that that made the call.  Also, plenty of programs use multiple threads together with sockets just fine.  It's trickier to get right than a single thread, but it's a perfectly acceptable approach if the programmer knows what he's doing, and it's commonly used.  As for whether it is beneficial compared to a multiplexed-single-thread approach, that will depend a lot on what *else* the thread needs to do other than sending/receiving.

Comment: "if a particular call is "blocking," it's probably going to block the process." - this is completely incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, immibis. I have updated the reply accordingly.